# Knee and muscle mobility following injury

Tags: injury, recovery, mobility

I am a footballer at a high level and I am undergoing problems with regards to growth. In November 14 I shattered new bone in my knee due to growth I was out for 10months and returned September Last year. I am stretching around 3 times a week and foam rolling with it for about 30 minutes a day. Throughout this season I have had little niggles with injury. However I have noticed I have quite poor from what I used to had knee mobility. When performing a simple quad stretch I am around 2" from by bum on the one leg and just touching on the other. When performing the stretch I get pain mainly around the tendons in my knee at the front patella and the tendon connecting knee to quad also I get some pain at the tendons at the rear of my knee with the connections of calf and hamstring. Is there something to do that I will eventually be able to sit on my heals?

Comment: This is really something that you should be asking a physical therapist. There may be many reasons that can't be determined without a hands on examination.